# Scheduled download of files from multiple URLs

Tags: python, curl, download, python-requests, wget

Once a month, my team needs to go out to a number of sources and download various documentation. My goal is to find a tool or create a script that can reach out on a schedule to multiple sources, download the most up to date document, and over-write the previous copy.

As my python skills are pretty rusty, I'm hoping there is something that exists already that I can at least utilize as a starting point. If not, I would greatly appreciate some direction for a starting point. It seems like the way to do this with Python would be through requests?

Comment: `Once a month` You have to **schedule the program** to run. So, you need a **scheduler**. `download various documentation.` You can use an **http library** to download stuffs. `over-write the previous copy` **IF** downloaded, delete previous and save the current, **ELSE** do nothing. `do this with Python would be through requests` Yes, that is one of the ways. You can also do it without Python. Opinion: **CURL** rocks!

Answer (score 1):

One line for each doc/URL, run from crontab or similar. Will conditionally download the URL if the server has a newer version of the resource than the local one:

```
curl --remote-name 
  --time-cond file.doc 
  https://example.com/p/file.doc
```

If you have curl 7.68.0 or later, you can even do etag conditions which makes it work interdependent of time:

```
curl --remote-name 
  --etag-compare etags.txt 
  --etag-save etags.txt 
  https://example.com/p/file.doc
```